# Measure for sumproduct with a many to one relationship

Tags: powerbi

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

I need a measure that will do SUM( every Value2* corresponding Value1)

I have tried the following but it does not work - I assume due to the tables being different number of rows.

```
Measure = SUMX(Table2, Table2[Value2] * Table1[Value1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a relationship like this

[image]

use this measure

```
Measure = 
SUMX(
    Table2, 
    Table2[Value2] * RELATED(Table1[Value1])
)
```

to get this result:

[image]

Comment: I get the following error using related: "The column 'Table1[Value1]' either doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship to any table available in the current context." . But I have a relationship via Month between Table1 and Table2.

Comment: You are missing something, check my edit.